# Conversion of pandas dataframe to sparse key-item matrix with composite key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, composite-primary-key

I have a data frame of 3 columns.  Col 1 is a string order number, Col 2 is an integer day, and Col 3 is a product name.
I would like to convert this into a matrix where each row represents a unique order/day combination, and each column represents a 1/0 for the presence of a product name for that combination.

My approach so far makes use of a product dictionary, and a dictionary with a composite key of order # & day.
The final step, which iterates through the original dataframe in order to flip the bits in the matrix to 1s is sloooow.  Like 10 minutes for a matrix the size of 363K X 331 and a sparseness of ~97%.

Is there a different approach I should consider?

E.g.,

```
ord_nb  day prod
1   1   A
1   1   B
1   2   B
1   2   C
1   2   D
```

would become

```
A   B   C   D
1   1   0   0
0   1   1   1
```

My approach has been to create a dictionary of order/day pairs:

```
ord_day_dict = {}
print("Making a dictionary of ord-by-day keys...")
gp = df.groupby(['day', 'ord'])
for i,g in enumerate(gp.groups.items()):
    ord_day_dict[g[0][0], g[0][1]] = i
```

I append the index represention to the original dataframe:

```
df['ord_day_idx'] = 0 #Create a place holder column
for i, row in df.iterrows(): #populate the column with the index
    df.set_value(i,'ord_day_idx',ord_day_dict[(row['day'], row['ord_nb'])])
```

I then initialize a matrix the size of my ord/day X unique products:

```
n_items = df.prod_nm.unique().shape[0] #unique number of products
n_ord_days = len(ord_day_dict) #unique number of ord-by-day combos
df_fac_matrix = np.zeros((n_ord_days, n_items), dtype=np.float64)#-1)
```

I convert my products from strings into an index via a dictionary:

```
prod_dict = dict()
i = 0
for v in df.prod:
    if v not in prod_dict:
        prod_dict[v] = i
        i = i + 1
```

And finally iterate through the original dataframe to populate the matrix with 1s where a specific order on a specific day included a specific product.

```
for line in df.itertuples():
    df_fac_matrix[line[4], line[3]] = 1.0 #in the order-by-day index row and the product index column of our ord/day-by-prod matrix, mark a 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a NumPy based approach to have an array as output -

```
a = df[['ord_nb','day']].values.astype(int)
row = np.unique(np.ravel_multi_index(a.T,a.max(0)+1),return_inverse=1)[1]
col = np.unique(df.prd.values,return_inverse=1)[1]
out_shp = row.max()+1, col.max()+1
out = np.zeros(out_shp, dtype=int)
out[row,col] = 1
```

Please note that the third column was assumed to be of name `'prd'` instead to avoid name conflict with built-in.

Possible improvements with focus on performance -

- If `prd` has single letter characters only starting from `A`, we could compute `col` with simply : `df.prd.values.astype('S1').view('uint8')-65`.
- Alternatively, we could compute `row` with : `np.unique(a[:,0]*(a[:,1].max()+1) + a[:,1],return_inverse=1)[1]`.

**Saving memory with sparse array :** For really huge arrays, we could save on memory by storing them as sparse matrices. Thus, the final steps to get such a sparse matrix would be -

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

d = np.ones(row.size,dtype=int)
out_sparse = coo_matrix((d,(row,col)), shape=out_shp)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [232]: df
Out[232]: 
  ord_nb day prd
0      1   1   A
1      1   1   B
2      1   2   B
3      1   2   C
4      1   2   D

In [233]: out
Out[233]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])

In [241]: out_sparse
Out[241]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [242]: out_sparse.toarray()
Out[242]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option you can try:

```
df.groupby(['ord_nb', 'day'])['prod'].apply(list).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1, x)).fillna(0)

#              A    B    C    D
#ord_nb day             
#     1   1  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
#         2  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```